# why you still need usual angular dependencies when you use typedefinitions?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to move move angular1.5 project  to use typescript.
My project compiled with webpack.
I noticed that although i included angular typedefinitions inside package.json

```
"@types/angular": "~1.5.19",
"@types/angular-mocks": "~1.5.5",
"@types/angular-route": "~1.3.2",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.5.37",
"@types/jwt-decode": "~1.4.28",
"@types/lodash": "~4.14.38",
"@types/source-map": "~0.1.29",
"@types/uglify-js": "~2.6.28",
"angular": "~1.5.8",
"angular-mocks": "^1.6.1",
"angular-route": "~1.5.8",
```

I still need  "angular": "~1.5.8" to be included.

If removed it gives me "Error cannot resolve module 'angular'"

here link to my [repo](https://github.com/shootermv/angular-seed)

Why javascript angular is still needed if typescript included?

Thanks to all wise guys who understand those things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Types` are definition of `modules` for `TypeScript`. If they are missing TypeScript compiler will show you an error.

You can read more about it [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/@types.html) and [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html).

Some packages have typings itself and don't need to use `@types` or `typings`, they usually have `typings` section in `package.json` file.

**Sumary:** 
If you use `TypeScript` and `package` don't have `typings` itself, you need to use `@types` or `typings`.

Comment: Thanks, as far as i understood - types are not typescript version of library but only declarations  for its modules? Am i right here?

Comment: @happyZZR1400 yes! :)